# Python function for boolean "and" operator?

Tags: python, functional-programming, standard-library

I'm suprised not to find the boolean (not bitwise) and operator in the operator module:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

Why is that so? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python `and` and `or` operators evaluate their expressions lazily, allowing you to use expressions like:

```
function_object and function_object(some, arguments)
some_value or produce_new_value(expensive, call)
```

safely.

This disqualifies them for a `operator` treatment, because you'd have to evaluate the expressions before passing them to the function.

In the above examples that means the `and` expression cannot be expressed using a `operator` function; if `function_object` is false-y it is probably not callable either, and if `some_value` is true-thy, you don't want to invoke the expensive function call.

It's easy enough to create your own functions if lazy evaluation is not required:

```
def and_(op1, op2):
    return op1 and op2

def or_(op1, op2):
    return op1 or op2
```

Comment: That's a very good point, especially since I would like to benefit from the lazyness. I'll ask my real question as a separate question. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own:

```
logical_and = lambda a, b: a and b
```